# How to write into JTextArea from other functions?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

my app works as network game, and I am getting messages from server and I wanna show them in my JTextArea. Code looks like this:

```
public class klient extend JFrame{
    ...declarations
    JTextArea areaText;

public klient(){
    setSize(600,300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("example");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().add(createComponents());
}

public JPanel createComponents(){
    JPanel mainPanel = ...
    ....
    Jpanel games = ....

    areaText = new JTextArea(...);
    areaText.setFont...
    ....
    areaText.setEditable(false);

    games.add(new JScrollPane(areaText, JscrollPane.V..., JScrollPane.H...));
}
}
```

and then I have classic main function

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    ....
    klient okno = new klient();
    ....
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Am I able to somehow add String from line into my JTextArea areaText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this.

```
okno.getAreaText().append(line);
```

Where getAreaText() method returns the areaText field of the class.

Comment: Yea, thats it. I was working all day, all night and couldnt figure it out :D Thanks